# Mocha testing javascript with inheritance

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am new to Mocha and Node but trying to write some Mocha tests on some JavaScript classes.

I have the following class:

```
function FormField() {
}

FormField.prototype.sanitizeFieldValue = function(value) {
    if (value == null || value.replace == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return value
        .replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ")
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
        .replace(/'/g, "\\'")
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/[\n\r]+/g, " ");
};

module.exports = FormField;
```

When I run my mocha tests on this file, everything works fine and the tests pass.

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var formfield = require("FormField");

describe("new Form Field Tests", function() {
   var ff = new formfield();
   describe("sanitizeFieldValue", function() {
        it("escapes apostrophe", function() {
            expect(ff.sanitizeFieldValue("'")).to.equal("\\\'");
        });
    });
});
```

However, I have another file which references the first:

```
TargetDateField.prototype = new FormField();
function TargetDateField() {
// some functions

}
module.exports = TargetDateField;
```

But I am not sure how to test this
I have tried the following but I keep getting FormField is not defined.

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var FormField = require("FormField").FormField;
var targetdatefield = require("TargetDateField");
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere where you want to use `FormField` you `require` the module that defines it.... except in your `TargetDateField.js` file, where you don't `require` it. That's why you are getting an error. You need to `require` it there too:

```
var FormField = require("FormField");

TargetDateField.prototype = new FormField();
// etc...
```

By the way, I strongly suggest writing your code to use relative paths when you want to load other modules that are part of the same package. At first glance, I'd expect `require("FormField")` to load something from `node_modules`. (Like when you do `require("chai")`.)